# "Take a tour of Stack Overflow for Teams" link is not working in the Stack Overflow Teams page - Firefox issue

Tags: bug, design, stack-overflow-for-teams, firefox

In the [Stack Overflow Teams](https://stackoverflow.com/teams) page, right corner bottom there is a messenger option there. By clicking on that, it opened a popup and inside that there is a "Take a tour of Stack Overflow for Teams" link. Clicking on that it opened an empty window.

When checking the browser's console, the below error message is displayed.

> Uncaught DOMException: A parameter or an operation is not supported by the underlying object

GIF for the issue:

[image: Tour page]

It happended in Mozilla Firefox browser, on Google Chrome there is no issue.

Mozilla Firefox: 86.0.1 (64-bit)
Operating System: Windows 10 Pro

**Expectation**: By clicking on the "Take a tour of Stack Overflow for Teams" link, it supposed to be redirected to [Tour page](https://stackoverflow.com/teams/tour)

Comment: Reproduced on Firefox. Doesn't happen on Chrome.

Comment: @Yatin : Yes, let me update in the post

Comment: Also reprod on Firefox on Android (well, it navigates to about:blank, can't confirm the error occurred)

Comment: I don't understand this trend of using js in place of basic html functionality. -_-

Comment: I get an _“Uncaught `DOMException`: The operation is insecure.”_ on Firefox Nightly 89.0a1. It’s probably CORS-related (the JS source does something like `newWindow = parent.window.open(); newWindow.opener = null; newWindow.location = newLocation;` — opening a new tab from an iframe, clearing the reference to the opener window, and then setting the location). But hey… why not just use an `<a href="`…`" target="_blank">`? I agree that JS isn’t really needed for this.